# Optimal solution of complex optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $Q(x)=a(x)e^{jb(x)}$ be a complex function of $x$. We want to approximate this function with $R(x)=\alpha e^{jx\beta}$ such that
\begin{align}
\text{arg}\min_{\alpha,\beta} \int_{-\frac{A}{2}}^{\frac{A}{2}} |Q(x)-R(x)|^2 dx.
\end{align}
Is there any closed form solution for optimal $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: As a first approximation, let $\alpha_0$ be the average of $|Q(x)|$ and let $\alpha_1+\beta_1x$ be the best linear fit to $\arg(Q(x)))$. Then let $\alpha = \alpha_0 \exp(\alpha_1 i)$, $\beta=\beta_1$. I doubt there’s a nice formlula in general.

Comment: That should say $\alpha=\alpha_0 \exp(i(\alpha_1 - \beta_1 A/2))$